# Reading from a text file, checking for correct information, then displaying it

Tags: java, bufferedreader

So I have successfully added a list of users with fake bank account information into a text file. Now I need someway to read them back into my program.

For example:

If I entered username - mattsmith
and PIN - 1234

The rest of Matt Smiths back account information would show up in the console, and I want to be able to do things like add money, check balance, and withdraw.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Here is the code that I have so far

**ATM CLASS**

```
public class ATM {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // variables
    String dash = "-------------------\n";
    int accounts = 0;
    Bank bank = new Bank();
    boolean login = true;

    // Scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Welcome screen
    System.out.print(dash);
    System.out.print("Welcome to the Bank\n");
    System.out.print(dash);

    System.out.println("Do you have an account with us? (y/n) ");

    String answer = scanner.nextLine();

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {

        while (login) {

            System.out.println("Username: ");
            String lUsername = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("PIN: ");
            int lPin = scanner.nextInt();

            if (lUsername.equals(SampleUser.myUserName)
                    && lPin == SampleUser.myPin) {
                login = false;
                System.out.println("\nLogin successful\n");
            }

        }

        Bank.menu();

    } else {

        // new user is created

        System.out.println("Enter your full name below (e.g. John M. Smith): ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Create a username: ");
        String userName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your starting deposit amount: ");
        double balance = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print(dash);
        System.out.print("Generating your information...\n");
        System.out.print(dash);

        int pin = bank.PIN();
        String accountNum = bank.accountNum();

        User user = new User(name, userName, pin, accountNum, balance);

        // new user gets added to the array list
        Bank.users.add(user);

        System.out.println(user);

    }

    try {

        File file = new File("users.text");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        BufferedWriter  bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.append(String.valueOf(Bank.users));
        bw.close(); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

**BANK CLASS**

```
public class Bank  {

// Generate a random 16 digit bank account number
public String accountNum() {

    int max = 9999;
    int min = 1000;

    int a1 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    int a2 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    int a3 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    int a4 = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    String accountNum = a1 + "-" + a2 + "-" + a3 + "-" + a4;

    return accountNum;
}

// Generate a random 4 digit PIN
public int PIN() {

    int max = 9999;
    int min = 1000;

    int PIN = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    return PIN;
}

public static void menu() {

    while (true) {

        System.out.print("\n1"); System.out.print(" - View Balance       ");
        System.out.print("3"); System.out.print(" - Deposit Money\n"); 
        System.out.print("2"); System.out.print(" - Withdraw Money     ");
        System.out.print("4"); System.out.print(" - Exit\n\n");
        System.out.print("I would like to: \n");

        Scanner bscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int mc = bscanner.nextInt();

        if (mc == 1) {
            System.out.print("Your current balance is: $" + SampleUser.getMyBalance() + "\n");
        } else if (mc == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter withdrawl amount: ");
            double wd = bscanner.nextDouble();
            SampleUser.myBalance -= wd;
            System.out.println("\n$" + SampleUser.getMyBalance() + " is your new account total");
        } else if (mc == 3) {
            System.out.print("Enter deposit amount: ");
            double dp = bscanner.nextDouble();
            SampleUser.myBalance += dp;
            System.out.println("\n$" + SampleUser.getMyBalance() + " is your new account total");

    }
    }
}

public static void readFile() {

}


// array list for users
static ArrayList users = new ArrayList(); {


};
```

}

**USER CLASS**

```
public class User implements Serializable{

String name;
String userName;
String accountNum;
int pin;
double balance;

public User (String name, String userName, int pin, String accountNum, double balance) {

    this.name = name;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.accountNum = accountNum;
    this.pin = pin;
    this.balance = balance;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getAccountNum() {
    return accountNum;
}

public void setAccountNum(String accountNum) {
    this.accountNum = accountNum;
}

public int getPin() {
    return pin;
}

public void setPin(int pin) {
    this.pin = pin;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

}

[1] http://prntscr.com/2jqm20

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? Also can you show a snippet of your text file.

Comment: @peeskillet I'm just stuck, I'm clueless on what to do next, screenshot will be up in a sec

Comment: Ok i understand you're stuck, but you have to explain what specificly has you stuck. We can't guess where your problem is. But we _can_ help you with a _specific_ problem if you clearly point out to us what that problem is.

Comment: And it looks like you've done a lot of work already, so you seem to be getting somewhere. But you're stuck. So where along in this code are you stuck at? What's the area of the program that's giving you problem? e.g. you can't get something to print on the screen <- this is a specific problem we can help solve.

Comment: @peeskillet Screenshot is up, I also commented under each item what they represent. So I'm trying to make a login screen for the bank, and if the username and pin match an account stored in the text file, then the rest of the information gets pulled down, if they username and pin dont match an account, then ill print an error. So basically my problem is I dont know how to read a file, and check it for specifics, if its even possible

Comment: @peeskillet also, I've since added a `toString` to the user class, so I can read the information

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45331/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-ks23)

Comment: @peeskillet I seem to be having a problem when I have more than one user in the text file, It's only checking for the first user, not any other one.

Comment: @peeskillet , solved my own problem, nevermind :)

Comment: @peeskillet Hi, after I retrieve a user balance, whats a quick and easy way to overwrite over the previous one in the text file?